# what is jquery keyword self refer to in self.setInterval? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, self

what is jquery keyword self refer to in self.setInterval? jquery

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what's your question.

Comment: We can't read your mind.Please explain in brief.

Comment: none of this has to do with jquery. `self`, unless otherwise defined somewhere in the same scope, refers to `window`

Comment: @PatrickEvans You should add that as an answer. Also note that `setInterval` only works in the context of the global object. Even if you copy it into another object, it has to be invoked with the global object as the execution context, or an error is thrown.

Comment: the `self` named variable is usually created to save the value of `this` in closure - http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Mar/28/JavaScript-windowSetTimeout-to-a-JavaScript-Class-method-or-function-with-parameters#5042

Answer (score 7):

Unless `self` has been defined somewhere in the same scope, it is a reference to the Window object. The Window object actually has 2 self-referential variables `self` and `window`

As such you could do `self.window.self.window.self.window.self.window.self`, if you were in the weird mood to.

As such your code

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
```

is equivalent to

```
var int = setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
```

or

```
var int = window.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
```

also you could just do

```
setInterval(clock,1000);
```

There is no need to wrap it in an anonymous function, unless you need to do other stuff besides run clock.

[window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self)

Comment: `top` is another reference to `window` in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript some programmers use a variable `self` or `that` to refer to function scope which is `this`. The `this` object refers to the current object or function.

If a function gets executed inside another function you will lose the reference to `this`.
A simple trick to workaround it is to set `this` to a variable outside the function.

There are ways to avoid these references by using jquery `$.proxy(function, this)` (IE8 compatible, not sure about IE7 and lower) or for modern browsers `(function(){}.bind(this))`

**UPDATE**

As Patrick pointed out, `self` by default is referenced to the active `window`. Useful inside frames for example.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_self.asp

Comment: self also refers to `window` unless otherwise defined.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is not a reserved word in JavaScript. However, there is a common convention of assigning `self` to the object the current method is executing in. For instance:

```
var myobj = {
    mymethod: function () {
        var self = this;
    },
};
```

The reason for this is to back up the `this` to a variable so you can do other cool things like asynchronous callbacks that affect the parent object.

Perhaps if you could give us more context we could explain what the `self` variable is set to in your problem.

Comment: by default `self` is the same as `window`